# configure entry points in simulink model to make it callable

Tags: matlab, simulink, beagleboneblack, generated-code

I've been handed a simulink model.  I'd like to use simulink's code generation features to compile it into a binary and then run it on an embedded system (a beaglebone black).    From there, I want to query it for output as a stand-alone component of a more complicated system.

I am having trouble finding where to specify the interface behavior to the compiled model.

I want to start the simulink model (with a python `os.system()` call, probably) with some default arguments (like starting parameter values for the model blocks), and then capture its output, which should be the values reported at each outport at each tick (the model has an internal clock and reports values at given intervals).

I have been able to blindly compile it into an `*.elf` binary and deploy it to the embedded device, and it runs, but the only thing that happens is i get the string `**** model running ****` on `STDOUT`.

1. What's the easiest way to specify command line arguments into this compiled binary?
2. If the answer is "generate the code and then edit it by hand to pass arguments in", how do I persist the hand edits between re-generations of the code when the simulink model changes?
3. How do i make simulink outports report on `STDOUT` ?